# Encoding in JUnit: Gradle vs Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, encoding, utf-8, junit

I have a project with some JUnit model tests, in Eclipse.

One of these tests asserts some special characters. It passes in Eclipse (`Run As` -> `JUnit Test`), but fails when ran with Gradle (`clean test`).

The failure: `org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[ü]> but was:<[�]>`, in the Gradle report.

I've added `tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {options.encoding = 'UTF-8}` to the build file, which fixed the compile-time encoding issues. But I still get the run-time error (see the failure above).

Adding `compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'` does not help.

The test runs on MacOS, and the project encoding is inherited from the OS (Windows + UTF-8, in my case).

Comment: Does your java file have UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @StefanBirkner Inherited from container, yes.

Comment: I'm facing a similar behaviour on Windows 8.1 - The only solution for me at the moment is to set GRADLE_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=utf-8 as system variable in Windows. But I consider that as an ugly workaround since a gradle build script should not rely on some external configuration.

Comment: I have filed a bug report to gradle for the missing possibility to configure the correct encoding for testing - see https://discuss.gradle.org/t/no-possibility-to-set-file-encoding-for-junit-tests-in-gradle-2-13-and-odler/17223/1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the encoding for the task, which compiles the test classes, too:

```
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
compileTestJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

Comment: every time i run into this crap i scratch my head thinking "how the f is this not the default:???"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to cover all Java compilation of both test and production code:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```